# Name of class of problems to make change

Tags: algorithm

When researching exercises to practice truncate and modulo I’ve come across a group
of similar problems. For example:

Make change using quarters, dimes,  nickels

To fill a barrel, use minimum pours from containers of gal, qt, pint

Transport grain efficiently given capacity & limitations of barges, trains and trucks

Is there a name for this class of problems or of the algorithm to solve? I’m looking
for a title analogous to the “Traveling Salesman Problem”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are problem of Dynamic programming.
They all specifically resembling to  COIN CHANGE PROBLEM.

please explain the tasks if i am worng.

link of coin change: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/

Comment: There even is an SO tag [tag:coin-change].

Comment: Thanks guys. I must have been way off on my search terms to not find page greybeard noted.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is known, in my experience, as the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The general idea being, given a list of things with certain dimensions (like size, value, or weight), optimize their fill into a limited space. The "make change" problem is a special case of the Knapsack problem.